# Possibilities with WiX setup

Tags: .net, installation, wix

Before I start to get into WiX I want to know if this is possible:

1. Is it possible to have user Input fields and get the values into a c# function like "OnBeforeInstall" and do something more with it?
2. If the Software is already installed and you just want to update it, is it possible to call a c# function right at the beginning of the Setup that returns a boolean so that specific Dialogs gets skipt?

Whole Idea:

On the first install it asks you about some informations that creates a config file for the programm. But if you just want to upgrade, it checks if the config file exists and if it exists, it will skip the dialogs that ask for the config Infos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [Wix Toolset manual](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/) that covers a *lot* of details. WiX can have a steep learning curve but certainly everything you're asking about seems doable.

There are [built-in dialogs](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface/) but if those are insufficient for your needs, you can certainly create [custom UI as well](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface-revisited/).

Almost everything within MSI/WiX is declarative and most elements can have `Condition` elements attached to disable their usage/launch if required (to disable unnecessary dialogs during re-install/upgrade). Searching for a file during the early phase of setup isn't uncommon and can be done with a standard [`FileSearch`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/filesearch.html).

Most of the time you shouldn't be thinking of writing C# code if there are declarative ways to achieve the same already built into the system. But for your config file editing, you'll probably have to drop down into a Custom Action there.

The most important thing I'd say is be prepared that there is a learning curve here, and you'll probably want to play around with a fair few of the concepts in some toy projects before trying to use it "in anger" for your real project.

Comment: Thanks for this info! But if I want to wirte a XML config file just before the Installation I will need c# i guess, that why I´m asking if this is possible :)

Comment: @SomePerson - and that's why I mention Custom Actions for that bit specifically.